# Show newly-inserted SQL data on main form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I’m having a little trouble figuring this one out. I’m fairly new to C#, but I feel like the answer to this should be simple.

I have a form that displays data which it pulls from an SQL database. Users can open a new window and add new entries to the database, and when they click OK, the info is inserted into the database and the window closes.

The problem is that once this happens, the info being displayed on the main form does not show the data that was just entered. I tried to add a function that refreshes the main form when the user submits, but the new info would not show up.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the newly-inserted SQL data to display on the main form? Here is my code for reference:

```
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO customParts (part_num, date, customer, orig_call, vendor, vendor_pn, price, delivery, packaging, notes) VALUES (@partnum, @getdate, @cust, @callout, @vend, @vend_PN, @cost, @deliv, @pkging, @notes)", conn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnum", partnum);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getdate", getdate);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", cust);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vend", vend);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callout", callout);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vend_PN", vend_PN);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", cost);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliv", deliv);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkging", pkging);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", notes);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ie)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ie.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close the connection
            conn.Close();
            //Reload the main window to show new changes
            mainForm firstForm;
            firstForm = new mainForm();
            //Close the window
            this.Close();
        }
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried adding this method to my main form:

```
public static void refreshThis()
{
    Form mainForm = new mainForm();
    mainForm.Refresh();
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
        finally
        {
            //Close the connection
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            mainForm.refreshThis();
            this.Close();
        }
```

But it still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I assume this is for Winforms instead of ASP.NET(tagged).

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, thanks!

Comment: To avoid an Exception check if your connection was not closed already if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Close) conn.Close();

Comment: I assume ConnectionState.Closed will work too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have the following couple of lines:

```
mainForm firstForm;
firstForm = new mainForm();
```

While these lines will create a new form, which will be updated, it will be destroyed as soon as you leave the finally block and the user won't ever see it.

I think what you really want is to expose a `Refresh` method in your `mainForm` class and call it from the sub form.

Comment: OK I tried this, but still couldn't get it to work. Perhaps I went about it the wrong way? I added what I did to the end of my post.

Comment: You're still creating a new instance of your `mainForm`. You need to refresh the instance that the user already has open.